# Segue doesn't transfer array

Tags: arrays, swift, segue

I cannot seem to understand why the array answers is empty whenever I run test the program.

When I use println(finalResultsSegue) in view controller 1, I can see the array of results, but when I pass it to answers in view controller 2 it goes to the next screen but the array remains empty.

### View Controller 1

```
@IBAction func submitAll(sender: UIButton) {

    let hasAnsweredAllQuestions = questions.reduce(true) { (x, q) in x && (q.usersAnswer != nil) }

    println("has user answered all questions?: \(hasAnsweredAllQuestions)")

    if hasAnsweredAllQuestions == true {

        for (index, _) in enumerate(questions) {
            userAnswers.append(questions[index].usersAnswer!)
            correctAnswers.append(questions[index].answer!)
        }
        if userAnswers.count == 3 {
                checkResults()
                }
            }
        }
    }

func checkResults() {
    let answer = map(zip(correctAnswers, userAnswers)){
        ($0.0 == $0.1) ? "correct" : "wrong"
    }
    var finalResults = answer.map({"The following answer is \($0)"})

    finalResultsSegue = finalResults

    println(finalResultsSegue)
}

@IBAction func nextPage(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("answerSummary", sender: sender)

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if(segue.identifier == "answerSummary") {
            var answerSummary = segue.destinationViewController as! QuizResultsViewController

            answerSummary.answers = finalResultsSegue
        }
    }
}
```

### View Controller 2

```
class QuizResultsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

var answers: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    println(answers)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got `prepareForSegue` as an nested function inside `nextPage`. Move it outside and it should work fine:

```
@IBAction func nextPage(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("answerSummary", sender: sender)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if let answerSummary = segue.destinationViewController as? QuizResultsViewController
        where segue.identifier == "answerSummary"

        answerSummary.answers = finalResultsSegue
    }
}
```

The fact you didn't have to prefix `func prepareForSegue...` with `override` is a hint that you've put `prepareForSegue` in the wrong place.

Comment: Ahh yes I should of seen that. Thank you for your help! Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a struct to store any 'global variables' that you want to send from one ViewController to another. Set a variable inside the struct and as long as the struct is defined outside of the class you can access it in any other classes within the project.